# Add HTML property conditionally in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to add a `aria-current` condition in React just if my path variable is null.

```
{props.path.map((values, index) => {
  const path = values.path ? `/${values.path}` : null;
  const aria = path !== null ? `aria-current="page"` : null;

  return (
    <li 
      className="breadcrumb-item"
      {...aria}
    >
      {path ? <a href={path}>{values.name}</a> : values.name}
    </li>
  );
})}
```

It is not working. Any idea how should I do it?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

Strings can be spread since they are iterable, but null is not. Spreading a string doesn't make sense here though, you want to spread in a prop.

## Solution

Create a prop object that can be spread into the element.

```
{props.path.map((values, index) => {
  const path = values.path ? `/${values.path}` : null;
  const aria = path !== null ? { "aria-current": "page" } : {};

  return (
    <li className="breadcrumb-item" {...aria}>
      {path ? <a href={path}>{values.name}</a> : values.name}
    </li>
  );
})}
```

[image: Edit add-html-property-conditionally-in-react]

### Why key is `"aria-current"` and *not* `ariaCurrent`?

[WAI-ARIA and Accessibility](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#wai-aria)

> Note that all aria-* HTML attributes are fully supported in JSX.
> Whereas most DOM properties and attributes in React are camelCased,
> these attributes should be hyphen-cased (also known as kebab-case,
> lisp-case, etc) as they are in plain HTML:
>
> ```
> <input
>   type="text"
>   aria-label={labelText}
>   aria-required="true"
>   onChange={onchangeHandler}
>   value={inputValue}
>   name="name"
> />
> ```

Comment: Ah beat me to it, one question on this though - should it be `ariaCurrent` in camel case as React likes it?

Comment: @Ayushya No, aria attributes are still standard for accessibility: https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#wai-aria

Comment: Aha, I should focus more on accessibility. Thanks!

Comment: @Ayushya No worries. :) I added a bit more explanation to my answer. Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese if you're using TypeScript it's handy to know that you have to put ```{/* @ts-expect-error valid aria attribute */}``` before the element on which you're spreading the aria attribute (at least this was the case in my Next.js app on the Link component)